# Traversing a DOM with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to find in a specific site an element within the DOM.
Inside the DOM there is a tag called "cufon".
assume the url is http://www.xyzw.com/
The code i use is the following:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.xyzw.com/');
$teams = $dom->getElementById('cufon');
```

at this point the $teams var suppose to contain all of the cufon elements inside the DOM but it contains nothing if i try to find for "div" elements it does find it all.
What is the problem?

Comment: does cufon get added with `javascript`?

Comment: No. as i see its fixed in the page.

Comment: there is a tag called cufon or there is a div with an id = cufon?

Comment: tag called "cufontext".

Comment: Then You should use `getElementsByTagName( 'cufontext' )`.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, there is a TAG called `cufontext` then trying to find a collection of nodes using one ID would only return one element ( IDs need to be unique ) so perhaps you want to find all elements of the specified tagname??

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.xyzw.com/');
$teams = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cufontext');
if( $teams ){
    foreach($teams as $team){
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

As we have not been given the actual url involved I had to test like this:-

```
/* random url - just happened to be open in browser just now */
$url='http://www.interparcel.com/';

/* the tag to search for */
$tag='div';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
$teams = $dom->getElementsByTagName( $tag );

/* As pointed out by @Pieter it would have always returned true so additional check */
if( $teams && $teams->length > 0 ){
    foreach($teams as $team){
        echo $team->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

This will spit out lots of content from the remote url - so if you are unable to find a tag called `cufontext` I'd suggest confirming there are tags of that name

Comment: Your if statement is unnecessary, as `getElementsByTagName()` will always return a `DOMNodeList` object.

Comment: there is a tag called cufontext for sure. i tried the same as you did and still no results. no idea why does the php selector is unable to find cufontext elements.

Comment: it is very strange that i can not find all the elements from inside the dom which contain the cufontext tag. do you know another method to traverse the dom and get specific content from it?

Comment: can you share the url so others may see for themselves?